# DataTable Select Method Limitation

Tags: c#, oracle11g

Is there a limitation in Select method of datatable? I am using oracle 11g in which I got following error -

> ORA-01795 maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000

Now while correcting I noticed that I am using `IN` clause in Select method filter expression of a datatable. e.g.

> //transactionIDs is a string variable which may have more than 1000 comma separated values
>   ldtRecords.Select("EM_ID NOT IN (" + transactionIDs + ")");

So just wanted to confirm if there is limit on that too?

Comment: That's an oracle not a .net error. So why should it be related to `DataTable`? https://forums.oracle.com/thread/958612

Comment: I not sure if its related to .net but since I got an error there, I want to make sure that there is no limitation here

Comment: The limitation is oracle as the error (and the link) suggests. The error was not raised on `DataTable.Select`(which is an in memory "query") but on (for example) `DataAdapter.Fill(table)`. Note that you should show your code.

Answer (score 0):

ORA-01795 is an Oracle database specific error. I think that clearly indicates there is a limitation in Oracle's Data Provider implementation.

I don't believe there is a hard limitation on the DataTable Select method. Maybe you can use a Reflector tool to examine the source code.